# How to escape html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security, xss

Im using [jQuery Markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) to allow users to input html... So they can input stuff like:

```
<h1>Foo</h1>
<p>Foobar</p>
```

However, I was watching http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3 and decided to try this piece of code into the input:

```
<script>alert('test');</script>
```

To my amazement, when I submitted the form and refreshed the page, the alert box came out. This is a security risk!

This is what I have in my view:

```
<div><%= comment.description.html_safe %></div>
```

The above renders any html, but is also prone to xss. So I tried:

```
<div><%= html_safe(comment.description).html_safe %></div>
```

But the above does not render any html. It actually displays the html as **text**, which is not the desired behavior.

I need to render the html and at the same time protect myself from xss. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<%= sanitize(comment.description) %>
```

Update:

To remove ALL tags use strip_tags

Comment: Yea sanitize renders html, and doesn't execute the alert from the JS. Interesting. But what implications does this have? I was watching http://railscasts.com/episodes/27-cross-site-scripting and Ryan B mentions that its "not quite as thorough, since it doesn't escape every html tag. which is not quite as secure" ...